# Intermittent Lock Wait Timeout Laravel DB Transaction (with 5 retries)

Tags: mysql, laravel, timeout, locking, innodb

We've been experiencing intermittent lock timeout errors (roughly 1-2 a day out of ~250).

On checkout, we get all of the users details, save the order, process any payments, and then update the order. I think it may be the secondary update that's causing it.

Example of our code (not exactly the same but close enough):

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($paymentMethod, $singleUseTokenId, $requiresPayment, $chargeAccount) {
    // create order locally
    $order = Order::create([
        'blah' => $data['blah'],
    ]);

    // handle payment
    $this->handlePayment();

    // update order with new status (with a secondary transaction for safety)
    DB::transaction(function () use ($order) {
        $order->update([
            'status' => 'new status',
        ]);
    }, 5);

}, 5); // Retry transaction 5 times - this reduced the lock timeout errors a lot
```

And the intermittent error we get back is (actual values removed):

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction (SQL: insert into `orders` (`user_id`, `customer_uuid`, `type_uuid`, `status_uuid`, `po_number`, `order_details`, `cart_identifier`, `cart_content`, `cart_sub_total`, `cart_tax`, `cart_grand_total`, `payment_type_uuid`, `shipping_address`, `uuid`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
```

I've read lots up on it and some people say increase timeout (seems like a workaround), optimistic locking (I thought transactions already do that), and other things.

From what I can tell from database breadcrumbs, the order create sometimes takes a long time (eg saw one at 3s, another at 23s for some reason as it's usually 50ms insert), and then the other things happen and it tries to update the order but the row is still locked from the create().

Notes:

- We have 4 foreign keys on the orders table (customer uuid, user uuid, order type uuid, order status uuid) - I feel that these may be causing issues.
- Some eloquent creates take 3s, others 23s (only checked issue ones). On most orders, request is 500ms max, so these are outliers.

Any suggestions?

**Solution: No primary key on orders uuid. Very silly mistake. Caused InnoDB to basically create a 6 byte key for index. And lock up from consecutive insert, then update..**

Comment: UUIDs are not consecutive; they are scattered all over.

Comment: @RickJames do you know what UUID's are? I believe you're confusing v4 UUIDs for sequential ID's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see "lock wait timeout" errors look at *other* transactions. Particularly harmful are long running transactions. You can spot those in `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G`. Climbing InnoDB history list indicates there are ones, too. Currently running long transactions will be listed in `information_schema.INNODB_TRX`.

Note if a transaction grabbed an exclusive lock it's not released until the end of the transaction, not the end of a query.

First, rule out long running queries. For example, slow UPDATE will hold a lock for its execution time.

After all queries are made reasonably fast, review your transactions. Make them as short as possible. Quite often clients open a transaction, execute a query or two then go to third-party API calls or do other heavy lifting and keep the transaction open. Other transactions meanwhile will be getting "Lock wait timeout".

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The latest deadlocks (last 3) show pretty much the same thing. ```MySQL thread id 1334946, OS thread handle 46998731650816, query id 1308220069 XXXX XXXX updating
update `orders` set `request_xml` = ?, `orders`.`updated_at` = ? where `uuid` = ?
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 364 page no 9 n bits 0 index GEN_CLUST_INDEX of table `XXXXX`.`orders` trx id 1328386487 lock_mode X```

Comment: From what I can tell from the above, it shows that the GEN_CLUST_INDEX which is created after the order insert query is locking the row so that the immediate update query can't run right away. Is that what you gather from it too? Any thoughts on how to combat that?

Comment: This one looks like same problem with insert then directly after update, but doesn't say how to solve unless I take the insert out of the transaction or something... https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39550/when-and-why-can-this-kind-of-deadlock-occur

Comment: Wait, is uuid not a primary key? It should be

Comment: It does not add up. InnoDB creates GEN_CLUST_INDEX from a six bytes internal integer field when a user doesn’t define the primary key and there are no unique indexes to serve as one.

Comment: Can you post the table structure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208089/discussion-between-jonathan-and-akuzminsky).

Comment: Solution was that uuid wasn't set as a primary key for that table. Very silly mistake. Much appreciated.